# Ruby state_machine gem and state persistence - am I missing something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I am looking to implement a state machine in one of my models, and I have been considering the  state_machine gem which seems popular and appears to have a nice, simple API.

Anyways, it seems like there is no concept of persisting the state of the model, since the documentation does not illustrate any way to map the state to a DB property using ActiveRecord or any other supported ORM.  I would expect to load an object from the DB, check its state if desired, and based on its state allow certain events/transitions to take place.

- Am I completely missing something here or is there no way to persist the current state?
- If not, how can a transient state useful for any persisted model whose state changes over long periods of time?
- Should I be used a different plugin, something more suited for workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the documentation goes, the state machine library works with any attribute, either one that's created with `attr_accessor`, an `@`-instance variable, or a database column. It does seem to be your responsibility to call `save` on the record if any changes have been made, though.

Comment: Since state machines are defined using namespaces, and the states themselves are symbols, I see no mapping between state machines and attributes like you are saying.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you are saying. In the [RDocs](http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/StateMachine/MacroMethods) I just found the following config option: `:attribute - The name of the attribute to store the state value in. By default, this is the same as the name of the machine.` I see that ActiveRecord is now saving the state value after changing the state machine to use a persisted attribute and then calling `save`.

Comment: I just confirmed in a unit test that calling `save` is not required to update the persisted state when using ActiveRecord. Any transition seems to result in an immediate DB update.